# How to install Roundcube Elastic skin

Tags: roundcube

How to install Elastic skin for Roundcube?

This responsive skin is a part of the latest Roundcube repository now, but the repo contains not compiled version, without required dependencies.

How to compile the skin?

Is there any page where I can download the compiled version with all required dependencies (including jquery, bootstrap etc.)